# How to read and visualize EK500 acoustic data with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocean, acoustics

As the question says. I have been using echopype for the visualization and processing of EK60 ocean acoustic data however I am unable to find any sources aside from using Echoview. Is this something that is even possible or is the instrument too outdated?

Tried to see if I could use file with previous echopype code however it doesn't accept the .ek5 file.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.